# Kubernetes Ingress redirecting to directory different than nginx's root

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Basically, I have a nginx conf with something like that :

```
server {
 server_name localhost;
 listen 80;
 root /var/www/projectA/public_html;
}
```

And a (working) ingress that redirects to the root without a problem :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: projectA.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: main-service
              servicePort: 80
```

Now, I'd need another host ingress, let's say medias.projectA.com, that shows/manages medias (pictures uploaded through projectA's forms).

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: medias-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: medias.projectA.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: main-service
              servicePort: 80
```

What I'm trying to set is as follows :

- projectA.com => /var/www/projectA/public_html
- medias.projectA.com => /var/www/projectA/medias

What I tried but failed : Changing the nginx's root to /var/www/projectA, and then set the main ingress's path to /public_html (instead of /), and the media ingress's path to /medias (instead of /) => Got 404

What I also tried : Setting a new nginx conf with a different port (81) that points to /var/www/projectA/medias/public_html as a root. Then create a new service "media-service" that listens to port 81 for the medias ingress => medias.projectA.com/ redirects me to projectA.com

```
server {
 server_name localhost;
 listen 80;
 root /var/www/projectA/public_html;
}
server {
 server_name localhost;
 listen 81;
 root /var/www/projectA/medias;
}
```

Added a new port 81 in main-service:

```
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 81
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
```

Ingress :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: medias-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: medias.projectA.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: main-service
              servicePort: 81
```

Still can't get to have medias.projectA.com/ point to /var/www/projectA/medias (always /var/www/projectA/public_html)

Comment: Mmmm...`- path: /medias` ?

Comment: @Hackerman I've tried adding a symbolic link projectA/public_html/medias -> projectA/medias, then changed the path of the ingress to /medias as suggested, but only got a 404. Also tried using a new service that listens on port 81, with no luck either (it redirects to the port 80 / main service instead)

Comment: Are you using ingess-nginx, or do you have ingress installed as service on host?

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, yes I solved this problem, I was missing a block "volumeMounts" in the deployment.yaml, adding that solved the problem